# Python Requests - Batch API calls

Tags: performance, post, python-requests, batching

I am working on an API to push records from a database to endpoint.

I have managed to write a piece of code which grabs the records, it's parsing them and finally pushing to API and works just fine.

It manages to push around 400 req/min and I was wondering if I can batch this requests to make it a bit more performant, but I can't wrap my head around how this can be achieved.

The API call url is:

http://call-url.com/service/{id}

Consider payload for id:

```
id = 101

{
"stars":3
"position":5
"date":"2002-04-30T10:00:00+00:00"
}
url = http://call-url.com/service/101
```

I am using python and requests module to push the records.

As we speak I am grabbing the records and parsing load for each individual id and pushing them.

I bumped into asyncio and threading so far, but I need to ensure I don't push the same request twice.

Is it possible to push more than 1 record at once?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize any AMQP message broker. RabbitMQ for example. The concept is simple, just check the [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html). Split your script to `main.py` (read DB, prepares payloads and push them to the queue) and `worker.py` (get payload from the queue and send to API), and then just spawn as many `worker.py` processes as you need...

Comment: Appreciate it, yes it makes sense and it looks like how I was visualizing it. I will give it a go.

Comment: @madlicksxxx make sure you don't miss Message acknowledgment section. It's very important.